# How to tilt NSView based on center?

Tags: swift, macos, core-animation, nsview

How can I tilt an `NSView` based on its center?

```
let view = NSView(frame: frame)
self.view.addSubView(view)
view.frameCenterRotation = -3.0
```

This tilts based on origin not by its center.

Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: I agree. This .frameCenterRotation is totally misleading.

Answer (score -2):

#### CALAyer approach:

```
var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
let radians:CGFloat = rotation / 180.0 * CGFloat.pi
transform = CGTransform.rotateAroundPoint(transform, radians,pivot)
view.layer?.setAffineTransform(transform)
```

**SideNote 1:** 
You can do this with view.setBoundsOrigin(pivot) + view.rotate(byDegrees: rotation) (But you have to take into account that If your flipping the coordinate sys, then you have to consider that as well)

**SideNote 2:**
Doing it with CALayer also enables the possibility for future animation